# TS: how to merge values in an array of objects into one array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I call the function

```
getAllUsers() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
}
```

with:

```
this.UserService.getAllUsers().subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res);
})
```

The output is:

```
[{id:1, name:'anna'}, {id:2, name:'john'}, {id:3, name:'victor'}]
```

but I would like to return an array of all names:

```
['anna', 'john', 'victor']
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.UserService.getAllUsers().subscribe(res => {
   const names = res.map(i => i.name)
   console.log(names)
})
```